# Trying to 'select' one days worth of items from sqLite Database [iOS/mac os]

Tags: database, sqlite

So, I have been banging my head against a few walls on this one (and have searched for answers here and else where).

Below are the searches I've used, to get closer to what I'm trying to end up with.

I'm really new to sqLite/databases, sorry in advance if I'm not making complete sense.

Below is what I've tried:

```
datetime(1536115105.62894, 'unixepoch'); -- used this to test the timestamps

SELECT strftime('%Y-%m-%d 23:59', 'now', 'localtime'); --- grabs todays date, localtime, sets to 11:59pm

SELECT strftime('%Y-%m-%d 23:59', 'now', 'localtime'); --- grabs todays date, localtime, sets to 00:00am

SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE timestamps BETWEEN strftime('%Y-%m-%d 23:59', 'now', 'localtime') AND strftime('%Y-%m-%d 23:59', 'now', 'localtime'); --- returns nothing.

SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE timestamps > strftime('%Y-%m-%d 00:00', 'now', 'localtime'); -- returns nothing.

SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE timestamps < strftime('%Y-%m-%d 00:00', 'now', 'localtime'); -- returns everything, which is confusing as there are transactions after this time?
```

.schema for 'transactions'

```
CREATE TABLE transactions (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, amounts INTEGER(20), timestamps INTEGER(20));
```

'transactions' data/table below.

```
id          amounts     timestamps      
----------  ----------  ----------------
1           450         1536115105.62894
2           450         1536115105.62894
3           450         1536115105.62894
4           551         1536115603.29054
5           10431       1536115603.29054
6           20004       1536115603.29054
7           450         1536115603.29054
8           123         1536115603.29054
9           1244        1536115603.29054
10          201         1536119203      
11          1100        1536118253.46948
12          1100        1536118253.46948
13          1100        1535599853      
14          1100        1535599853      
15          1100        1535599853      
16          123         1535945759      
17          1200        1536032309      
18          450         1536161578      
19          450         1536161578      
20          450         1536161578      
21          100         1536507178      
22          100         1536507178      
23          100         1536507178      
24          25          1534260778      
25          25          1534260778      
26          25          1534260778
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the following could be the basis for a solution. Basically it converts the date/time values to the same format for the comparison.

This converts the **timestamp** column to a **datetime** format (yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss) for the comparison :-

```
SELECT *
FROM transactions 
WHERE datetime(timestamps,'unixepoch') BETWEEN '2018-09-05 02:00' AND '2018-09-05 23:59'
;
```

This converts the **values** to be compared to **timestamp** format (drops thousandths) :-

```
SELECT *
FROM transactions 
WHERE timestamps BETWEEN strftime('%s', '2018-09-05 02:00') AND strftime('%s', '2018-09-05 23:59')
;
```

- Note local time, use of 'now' removed for simplicity.

Here's the full SQL that was used to test the above :-

```
DROP TABLE If EXISTS transactions;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS transactions (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, amounts INTEGER(20), timestamps INTEGER(20));
INSERT INTO transactions (amounts, timestamps) VALUES
    (450,1536115105.62894),
    (450,1536115105.62894),
    (450,1536115105.62894),
    (551,1537115603.29054)
    ;

SELECT *, 
    datetime(timestamps,'unixepoch') AS dt,
    strftime('%Y-%m-%d 02:00','2018-09-05') AS cmprtime1,
    strftime('%Y-%m-%d 23:59','2018-09-05') AS cmprtime2,
    strftime('%s','2018-09-05 02:00') AS cmprts1,
    strftime('%s','2018-09-05 23:59') AS cmprts2
FROM transactions;

SELECT *
FROM transactions 
WHERE datetime(timestamps,'unixepoch') BETWEEN '2018-09-05 02:00' AND '2018-09-05 23:59'
;

SELECT *
FROM transactions 
WHERE timestamps BETWEEN strftime('%s', '2018-09-05 02:00') AND strftime('%s', '2018-09-05 23:59')
;
```

The results from running the above being :-

The first query (demonstrates the converted values) :-

[image]

The second query (converts timestamp column to datetime format for compare) (selects 3 of the 4) :-

[image]

The third query (converts comparison values to timestamps) (selects 3 of the 4) :-

[image]

- To reiterate, conversion to localtime/use of **now** not used for simplicity.

Answer (score 2):

`strftime()` returns a string (like `'2018-09-05 00:00'` with some of your formats). You're comparing that string against things like `1536115105.62894`.

If your timestamps column is declared as holding REAL values, then sqlite tries to losslessly convert `'2018-09-05 00:00'` to a number, which fails. And since it fails, it falls back to the non-converting comparison, where all numeric values are less than any string.

If timestamps is a TEXT column, well, `'1536115105.62894'` is going to be less than `'2018-09-05 00:00'`.

[More information](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#comparison_expressions).

EDIT:

So, if you want to compare times, you have to compare them in the same form - as strings having the same format (Don't compare `'YYYY-mm-DD'` against `'HH:MM'`), or as numbers meaning the same thing (Don't compare julian days against a unix time), whatever form you prefer (Numbers are going to be more efficient though). But you can't compare a string holding a human readable time against the number of seconds and expect it to just work.

Comment: This is where I'm getting 'lost', saved the timestamps as INTEGERS, thinking that would make the most sense for later, so that I could compare/grab/etc what I needed for queries into the database.

Also added the .schema for the table; first post; so only thought after how that might help add context to what I'm trying to do.


(And really new with this, so I'm assuming I've just done something wrong)

Comment: @NathanWainwright You have fractional seconds in a bunch of those timestamps, so why use INTEGER when you want to store REAL values? (It works due to the way sqlite stores values in columns, but it's misleading and confusing).

Comment: Thanks for the input btw; puts me on a different direction and gets me closer to my resolution. :)